# Windows("ETY Tracker V1.2.xlsm").ScreenUpdating = False

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Could you please help to solve the problem I am facing,when i run the program its throwing me an error "Object dosen't support this property or method"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   'Application.Visible = False
   'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Windows("ETY Tracker V1.2.xlsm").ScreenUpdating = False
   UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

please help...I also tried both application .visible but it will close all the active workbooks we have, and application.screenupdating will not allow me to edit or open any other sheet other than the present user form.

Comment: The error occurs because `Windows()` object doesn't have a `.ScreenUpdating` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to hide the workbook and just show the form?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Or hide Excel and show the form?  This won't close the workbooks - they're just inside the application which in itself is hidden.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.Visible = False
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Darren, I'm trying to hide the workbook and just show the form the program with ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False is helpful. 
Thank you very much

Comment: is there a way to specify the ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False to a specific file name by any change.

Answer (score 0):

`Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating` doesn't stop users from interacting with Excel, it just stops them from seeing the interaction.

Try `Application.Interactive = False`, but remember to set it back to true or you will have to close your excel application.

Comment: Thank you very much for the interactive but I was truing to hide the background data. I am using ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False. thank you very much.